# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift

Me aparece el siguiente error al momento de correr la aplicación:

```
objc[1951]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0xd14044c) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0xced8b78). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-03-10 10:31:06.170 Vehiculos[1951:137518] Unknown class MyTableCarViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-03-10 10:31:06.316 Vehiculos[1951:137518] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewController 0x78775e30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ImageView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(   0   CoreFoundation                      0x01108bf2 __exceptionPreprocess + 194
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007a2e66 objc_exception_throw + 52
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01108b21 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x003ea90d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 238
4   Foundation                          0x00318476 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 162
5   Foundation                          0x00317fe8 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
6   UIKit                               0x016d5a9e -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 80
7   Foundation                          0x00339b5f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 309
8   UIKit                               0x019833ad -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 138
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007b8177 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 51
10  CoreFoundation                      0x010a8180 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 272
11  UIKit                               0x01981a6c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2102
12  UIKit                               0x016dcd23 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 437
13  UIKit                               0x016dd770 -[UIViewController loadView] + 197
14  UIKit                               0x019973ef -[UITableViewController loadView] + 90
15  UIKit                               0x016ddae9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 188
16  UIKit                               0x016e4c00 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 114
17  UIKit                               0x017088d3 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 204
18  UIKit                               0x0171455b -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1438
19  UIKit                               0x017269fd -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 836
20  UIKit                               0x01727ebd -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 70
21  UIKit                               0x0194b69a -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 232
22  UIKit                               0x015e57e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1457
23  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007b81b9 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 59
24  QuartzCore                          0x061ec679 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 141
25  QuartzCore                          0x061df503 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
26  QuartzCore                          0x061df359 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 21
27  QuartzCore                          0x06168f57 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 339
28  QuartzCore                          0x06197d4c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 498
29  QuartzCore                          0x0619985c _ZN2CA11Transaction17flush_transactionEv + 38
30  UIKit                               0x0150845b _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 222
31  UIKit                               0x01dccead __handleEventQueue + 6148
32  CoreFoundation                      0x010a7edf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
33  CoreFoundation                      0x0108bfa7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 519
34  CoreFoundation                      0x0108b434 __CFRunLoopRun + 1124
35  CoreFoundation                      0x0108ad5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 395
36  CoreFoundation                      0x0108abbb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
37  GraphicsServices                    0x0530ab4c GSEventRunModal + 177
38  GraphicsServices                    0x0530a9c7 GSEventRun + 80
39  UIKit                               0x0150fff3 UIApplicationMain + 148
40  Vehiculos                           0x000a5901 main + 145
41  libdyld.dylib                       0x0364b799 start + 1
42  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Necesito entregar este proyecto hoy mismo y no puedo hacer que funcione.

Aquí está el [proyecto completo](https://github.com/aaronpean/Vehiculos) por si gustan verlo.

Comment: en el repositorio no esta el xcodeproj. De todas formas te esta diciendo que hay una UIImage por ahi que no le gusta nada como la has dejado. Seguramente no la tienes reverenciada en un IBOutlet y si en el xib

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, soy nuevo en esto de Xcode, no sé si me podrías apoyar en esto... Donde puedo verificar lo que mencionas?

Answer (score 1):

En tu `Storyboard` tienes un controlador al que has establecido su `customClass` a `MyTableCarViewController`.

Sin embargo, esta clase no existe en el repo. De ahí el mensaje:

> Unknown class MyTableCarViewController in Interface Builder file.

Al no encontrar la clase, el `Storyboard` debe intentar cargarse con un `UIViewController` normal, y como tienes establecidos varios `outlets`, y un `UIViewController` normal no contiene ninguna propiedad `ImageView`, pues te da esa excepción.

Tiene pinta de que has borrado esa clase **accidentalmente**, o quizá la hayas **renombrado**.

O bien le asignas en el Storyboard la clase correcta, o bien creas dicha clase con los outlets que necesita

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tenía un outlet al cual cambié el nombre, eso provocó que en el inspector de conexiones existieran un outlet de más.

Deberías de revisar el outlet que tenía el nombre imageView:

```
      @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView
```

Y en el Inspector de Conexiones borrar el outlet que no tenga referencia.